# .OnModelCreating causes timeout and exception

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I am in the enviable position of needing to debug someone else's convoluted code. I am finding that the code times out and throws an exception 
The thread 0x3e4c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in mscorlib.dll

the 'base' in this code refers to IdentityDbContext

I thought the connection string might be wrong due to the sqlexception, but I have double checked that several times.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().Property(job => job.SalaryMax).HasPrecision(10, 2);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().Property(job => job.SalaryMin).HasPrecision(10, 2);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: What does exception say? Any inner detail like stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
The issue was unrelated to the question sadly.
Turned out to just be a typo in the web.config file.
Sorry to waste anyone's time.